# How can I tell if a Wi-Fi hotspot is WPA or WPA2?

Tags: network, wifi, security

I want to print out a QR code for a Wi-Fi hotspot, so other people can easily connect to it with their iPhones and such, and the QR-code-maker has me choose between "WPA" and "WPA2".

How do I find out whether a Wi-Fi hotspot, in my MacBook's Wi-Fi history, is WPA or WPA2?

In my Wi-Fi network list, it's listed as "WPA/WPA2 Personal".  I assume that means "try WPA2, and if that doesn't work, then try WPA".  Is there any way to tell if it actually used WPA2?

Answer (score 2):

You can find this out by holding <kbd>Option</kbd> and clicking on the WiFi icon in the Menu bar.

It will open up a "menu" with additional options and details including the type of security you're using.

[image: WiFi Advanced Menu]

If you see your network say WPA/WPA2 Personal, it means it supports both. This is what the *Access Point* supports.  In my case, I disabled WPA (and thusly it doesn't show up).  You can choose either QR code and the client will be connected.

Comment: @ProGrammer The OP wants to create a QR code to facilitate joining his network (for his clients or guests, I presume) and needed to know how to figure out if he was using WPA or WPA2